# Custom non auto-incrementing ActiveRecord "id" column possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to be able to use a custom id (instead of the auto-incrementing default ones) for a Rails model. Basically, all the ids will be iTunes store ids, which are just long integers. Is it possible to turn off the default auto-incrementing ids and require that one be set? These ids will also be used as foreign keys in other models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
create_table :blah, {:id => false} do |t|
  t.int :my_custom_int_id
end
execute "ALTER TABLE blah ADD PRIMARY KEY (my_custom_int_id);"
```

Comment: You will also need to add `set_primary_key :my_custom_int_id` (Rails 3) or `self.primary_key = :my_custom_int_id` (Rails 4) in your model.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the id before you save the model.

```
a = Model.new
a.id = 8888 #from itunes
a.save
```

However, you should consider a separate field called `itunes_id` instead of this approach.

Comment: I am currently using a separate `itunes_id` field as you describe. The problem is that the API I'm using returns itunes ids so it's a pain to do an extra lookup for itunes_id -> my model id all the time.

Comment: I really like how you said what he should do, but also offered your advice.. best practice... :)

Comment: @daveatflow That is personal opinion not best practice IMO.